# How to share a public key for OAuth2 JWT validation?

Tags: validation, oauth-2.0, public-key-encryption, jwt

I am implementing an app that connects to an OAuth2 server and it gets back a Json Web Token (JWT).  I am passing the token along and I want to independently validate that the token came from the issuing source.

I can do this, no problem, with the public key from the issuing source.  I have it available to me for now.  Everything works.

But what if the OAuth server changes the signing key?  How does the validating app get the new key?  Is there a "best practices" convention for sharing the public key from an OAuth2 server?  Do we just expose it from an endpoint on the auth server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no solution that is standardized as part of the OAuth 2.0 protocol suite (today).

It was considered to be a single-domain problem that would be solved in various ways that were considered to be out of scope for the core OAuth specifications (much like the API between Resource Server and Authorization Server is/was), and much like any PKI based mechanism in general works today.

But OpenID Connect is a cross-domain SSO protocol that was built on top of OAuth 2.0, which also defined a more standardized option of dealing with key distribution in the form of JWKs URIs as part of the Discover, see the `jwks_uri` entry at:

> REQUIRED. URL of the OP's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document. This
> contains the signing key(s) the RP uses to validate signatures from
> the OP. The JWK Set MAY also contain the Server's encryption key(s),
> which are used by RPs to encrypt requests to the Server. When both
> signing and encryption keys are made available, a use (Key Use)
> parameter value is REQUIRED for all keys in the referenced JWK Set to
> indicate each key's intended usage. Although some algorithms allow the
> same key to be used for both signatures and encryption, doing so is
> NOT RECOMMENDED, as it is less secure. The JWK x5c parameter MAY be
> used to provide X.509 representations of keys provided. When used, the
> bare key values MUST still be present and MUST match those in the
> certificate.

This would expose the key material over HTTPs protected channel, effectively leveraging the SSL CA for publishing and rollover of JWT signing key material.

At some point the `jwks_uri` definition may be part of the standardized OAuth 2.0 protocol extensions as well, but for now you'd have to rely on a custom agreement between Client and Authorization Server to do so. That may not be too hard to implement yourself though.

You may get lucky if your Authorization Server happens to be an OpenID Connect provider as well and uses the same key material for signing ID tokens as well as JWT access tokens.

Updated 4/22/2019: the Authorization Server metadata document is now also standardized it its own OAuth 2.0 extension OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server Metadata [RFC8414](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8414)